# List updated when a row was insert/updated in DB

Tags: java, javascript, html, wicket

I'm working with java/wicket and I need to develop a functionality that shows on real time,  every new request that arrives from *clients_request* table into a list in the page.

I make this functionality with a script that every second clicks a button 
that query the bd and then reload all the table content.

There are any way to observe the bd and reload the page only when a new change on this table occurs ?

Answer (score 4):

If you would like the server to handle the updates (push instead of pull), you can use `WebSockets`, as can be seen here: http://wicketinaction.com/2012/07/wicket-6-native-websockets/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of programatically clicking a button change it at least to use a [AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior.html)

Answer (score 0):

We have a feature that has similar functionality. What we did was quite a complex solution, so I won't talk you through all of the details, but just outline it and if you think that's something you're looking for I will amend the answer with a full explanation.

To begin with, we solve this problem this way because polling doesn't work in our case, and as I understand it doesn't in yours as well.

What we do is make an asynchronous call on a special URL that maps to a handler which is **outside the page**. This is important: if it was inside a page (e.g. a behavior or a component on the page) then during the call the page would be locked and the user couldn't interact with other components on the page.

The way we achieve the asynchronous call is via some javascript, which makes an ajax request to a URL of that handler as soon as the page loads. In the call we include some information about what data we're waiting for, and what the callback URL is.

Then the handler simply waits for the events that would trigger the re-rendering of the,  components in question (so it holds on to the request, in other words).

When an event occurs, we return an ajax response with some javascript to be evaluated, that makes another ajax request; this time, the URL points to some behavior that would re-render the component. That behavior then re-renders the component and also evaluates some javascript to make a call to the waiting URL again. And it continues like that until one of the links in the cycle is broken.

If this sounds like something that could work for you, leave a comment. I will gladly include more details about how all of this is done then.

Comment: This sounds like a very complicated work-around for something simple. Can you tell why polling is not working for you? (And how you poll?)

Comment: Because there is no way to reliably pre-determine how long one can wait until the next update in data occurs, and the update frequency can vary from multiple updates every second to one per hour, which is more likely to be the case. So if we make the polling on a short interval, we put unnecessary load on the server, if we make it on a long one - we won't display data as soon as it's available (which is crucial).

Comment: Ah, I see. You have implemented 'long pulling'.